# Problem emptying a collection, it is not saved EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, easyadmin

For an entity with multiple properties, I have a form that shows one of those properties which is a collection.

I have this form with EasyAdmin, I can add and remove items from the collection, the problem is that I cannot remove all of them the changes are not saved or even if there is only one item left, if I delete it, it is not saved.

**Solution I have found**

The error I have when deleting offers, was that when trying to remove all they were not deleted on the database, it seems that when the entire body of the empty POST does not execute anything on the database, because if you put the offers in the Bike form along with all properties, if you let them be removed.

Therefore, the solution I take is to add an extra field as hidden, so that when the post is sent without any discount, it will not be empty.

Entity Bike:

```
class Bike{
    // More properties    

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bike\Offer", mappedBy="bike", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $priceOffers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->priceOffers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Adding, removing items and getter methods
}
```

Entity Offer:

```
class Offer{
    // More properties    

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bike", inversedBy="priceOffers")
     */
    private $bike;

    // getter and setter methods
}
```

Entity in EasyAdmin:

```
bike_offers:
    class: App\Entity\Bike
    role: ROLE_MANAGER
    form:
        fields:
            - property: 'priceOffers'
              type: 'collection'
              css_class: 'offers-collection'
              type_options:
                entry_type: App\Form\Bike\OfferType
                by_reference: false
                label: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `allow_delete` option and set to `true`.

```
type_options:
  allow_delete: true
```

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/easyadminbundle/collection-type

Comment: This has not worked for me, the docs says: allow_delete: (optional, default true) a boolean value indicating if uploaded files can be deleted directly in the edit/new form;